# Как разделить массив на несколько частей по 25 значений и потом вывести значения каждого из массивов в строку?

Tags: php

Вот у меня есть массив, содержащий много-много разных значений (цифры). Мне нужно разделить этот массив на более мелкие массивы по 25 значений и вывести все значения из каждого нового массива на новую строку (и даже если в последнем массиве получится останется меньше 25-и значений, то всё равно вывести их). Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам поможет функция PHP [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-chunk.php), которая разбивает массив на несколько мелких по N элементов.  Например:

```
array_chunk( [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 3) // даст [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8] ]
```

Склеить элементы массивов можно функцией [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php). Например:

```
implode( ":", [1,2,3]) // даст "1:2:3"
```

Сможете дальше сами?

Comment: А это сработает если я выбираю это числа из БД и преобразую это в массив mysqli_fetch_array?

Comment: В `array_chunk()` нужно подать один одномерный массив значений. Как вы его получите – вне этого вопроса. Скорее всего, вы его будете собирать в цикле, получая очередной результат через `mysqli_fetch_array()`.